# AJAX problem with retrieving data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I've got a problem with receiving data from my PHP script. I'm sending form data via AJAX to PHP, but it seems that the values are empty but in my url the values are set. So why I don't get my values back in JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Schachbrett</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            table {
                width: 800px;
                height: 800px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("button").onclick = pre_generate;
            }

            function pre_generate() {
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var columns = document.getElementById("columns").value;
                var rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
                var url= "chess2.php?columns="+columns+"&rows="+rows;
                request.onreadystatechange = generate;
                request.open("GET", url, true);
                request.send(null);
            }

            function generate() {
                if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
                else {

                }
                //
                /*for(var i=0; i<=8; i++) {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("table").innerHTML = "<tr id='"+i+"'></tr>";
                    for(var j=0; j<=8; j++) {
                        document.getElementsById(i).innerHTML = "<td></td>";
                    }
                }*/
                //document.getElementsByTagName("table").css("width", 100*columns+"px").css("height", 100*rows+"px");

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="">
            <input id="columns" type="text" name="columns" placeholder="Zeilen">
            <input id="rows" type="text" name="rows" placeholder="Spalten">
            <input id="button" type="submit" name="send" value="Generieren">
        </form>
        <table>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['columns']) && isset($_GET['rows'])) {
        $cols = $_GET['columns'];
        $rows = $_GET['rows'];

        echo $cols . "|" . $rows;
    }
    /*else {
        alert("Bitte geben Sie die Anzahl der Spalten und Zeilen ein!");
    }*/
?>
```

Thanks for your help. I really don't know what is wrong with it because I already did another lesson in this style and it worked just fine.

Comment: Your URL is `"chess2.php?cols="+columns+"rows="+rows;` and yet you try and get the one value as `$_GET['columns']` - `cols` != `columns`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote incorrectly. I changed it in the code but it still does not work.

Comment: another small snag: `var url= "chess2.php?columns="+columns+"&rows="+rows;` don't forget `&` in between the variables

Comment: keep eyes on console for errors .. cause I think you'll get `request` is undefined .. so after you make changes like previous comments mentioned .. use `request.onreadystatechange = function(){  // Check the status Here }` first before you put it into another `generate` function  .. If you got the expected alert from it you can then check the status in another function

Comment: request.readyState is 4 and request.status is 200. All is like it should but the request.responseText still is empty. I don't know maybe my server is doing weird things or something.